# I have problems with the connect() function

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I was watching a Godot 3 tutorial to make the effect of some bushes disappearing, but connect() doesn't work.

The script is not one of the node's own to be recycled, so I can't set signals for that.

```
extends AnimatedSprite2D

func _ready():
    self.connect("animation_finished", self, "_on_animation_finished")
    frame = 0
    play("Animate")

func _on_animation_finished():
    queue_free()
```

I tried to see how to solve it in forums but what I tried doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I already solved it:

```
extends AnimatedSprite2D

func _ready():
    animation_finished.connect(_on_animation_finished)
    frame = 0
    play("Animate")

func _on_animation_finished():
    queue_free()
```

And make sure the animation is not looped.